# Registering Websocket connections with Event Pages

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the initialization for my Event Page, I'd like to create a WebSockets connection via [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) and wake up the page whenever data comes in on that connection.

I suspect this isn't possible and I'll have to use a Background Page, but is there any clever way I can use Event Pages instead so I don't make my users incur the perf hit?

Comment: @apsillers put that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this simply because Event Pages are designed to unload when not in use. Whenever the page unloads, it will close any WebSocket connections. If it never unloads, then you effectively have a persistent background page.